# Android: How do I communicate to a STICKY Service if the app is alive or not? Is there an Android built-in way of doing that?

Tags: android, android-service

I created a service that get the user location even if the app is killed. The service is running perfectly and it get's the location correctly even if the app is killed. Which is the optimal/safer way to detect if the app is still alive to send the location either to main activity(If the app is alive or running on the background) or to a backend(if the app is killed)?. This is what I have so far(I'm checking the permissions on the main activity if someone wants to know, that's why I disabled them here):

```
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public class GPSService extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        listener= new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //To transfer the data to the main activity I use broadcast receiver in the main activity, using an intent filter location_update
                 Intent intentSendLocationMainActivity = new Intent("location_update");
                Log.d("Location-update",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
                intentSendLocationMainActivity.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
                //I need to differentiate here if the app is killed or not to send the location to main activity or to a server
                sendBroadcast(intentSendLocationMainActivity);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent activateGPSIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                activateGPSIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(activateGPSIntent);

            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //noinspection MissingPermission, listen for updates every 3 seconds
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed, Removing update location listener");
        //unregistering the listener
        /*if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }*/

    }

    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");
        //here you can call a background network request to post you location to server when app is killed
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Warning: App killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //stopSelf(); //call this method to stop the service
    }
}
```

And in the manifest file I have

```
<service                                                        
       android:name="applicatives.GPSService"   

       android:exported="false"/>
```

I came up with a possible solution, set an "isAlive" boolean on the onResume() and on the onStop() methods of the mainActivity and then use that to commnunicate to the service that the app is dead or alive.....

1) Is there a built-in way of checking that?
2) In case there isn't, will that boolean suffice?

Comment: If you send the data via a broadcast `Intent`, you don't need to care if the `Activity` is running or not. If the `Activity` is running, it can listen for the broadcast `Intent`, if it isn't running, then it won't listen. Your `Service` can listen all the time.

Comment: but I need to know if it's dead not because I'm worry if it's gonna crash, but because I need to send data to a server if the app is closed, and I need to make the distinction

Comment: You need to define "closed", then. I'm afaid that isn't so easy on Android.

Comment: wow...I thought it would be easy. Couldn't I put a boolean on the service and communicate to the service that the app is closing put the boolean isAlive to false and then when the activity starts again in the future send a message to the service saying that the app is running again and put that boolean to true?.......if not, could you at least give me a lead on how to do it?....even if it's not easy?

Comment: The problem is the definition of "closed". What does "closed" mean to you?

Comment: App can be in the background and active, but the user can't see it; App (process) can be killed by Android; User could have "exited" the app (ie: all activities are "finished"); Why do you need to know this? Seems a strange requirement. You still can't tell if the user will see what you send to the activity.

Comment: I need it cause I have a backend API where I check where the user is when the app is closed and then I need to check for events near him and send him notifications.......am I complicating things too much?

Comment: You still need to define what you mean by "the app is closed"

Comment: the user slides the app to "close it" like you close most apps......

Comment: This makes no sense. All that does is remove the app from the "list of recent tasks". The app may be running (ie: have active activities) or it may not be running. There is no difference. There may be an OS process running hosting the app, or there may not be. Just swiping the task from the list of recent tasks doesn't necessarily do anything. Your definition of "closed" doesn't make sense. When do you need to notify your server? What is the condition?

Comment: wow, you opened my mind with that, I thought that was the only way of "killing the app"...I just want to contact the server with the user location when the app is "dead"(whatever that means) to push notifications from the server to the user device....If that doesn't make sense please tell me what is your definition of "dead" and if it is possible what I want to do and which is the common approach to do this.....I'm using firebase for the notifications

Comment: Why dont you want to contact the server if the app is running? Whats the difference?

Comment: it's different....if the app is running I send the data to an activity for operations regarding UI and stuff, if the app is "dead"(again, whatever that means), I need to send it to server for notifications to attract the user back in.........I have opened mind and I like to hear your opinion, is this possible or does it make any sense? how do you define an app being closed? I still don't have that clear....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I still don't get your architecture (see discussion in comments). In any case, even if the app is "running", it could be in the background, which means that even if you sent data to the app, the user wouldn't necessarily see it. In my opinion your architecture is flawed.

I would use a bound `Service`. Have your `Activity` bind to the `Service`. If the `Activity` is no longer running (ie: it finished, or Android killed the process hosting the `Activity`), your `Service` will get a call to `onUnbind()`. In this case you know that the `Activity` is "dead".

Comment: Please note that OP's service is running in the same process as the app (judging by how it is defined in manifest), therefore if the app is killed then the service will be dead too.

Comment: @Vasiliy If `Service` returns `START_STICKY` it will be restarted by Android after the process is killed.

Comment: Sure. I just meant to say that this part is irrelevant: "or Android killed the process hosting the Activity". In this case, the service will be dead too and will (probably) not get a call to `onUnbind()`

Answer (score 0):

From the question and comments I can digest the following requirements:

1. If `MainActivity` is in a "started" state (i.e.  state between `onStart()` and `onStop()`), which means that it is visible to the user (but might be obscured by e.g. dialog), data need to be sent to that `Activity`.
2. If `MainActivity` is in "stopped" state (i.e. state before `onStart()` or after `onStop()`), which means that it is not visible, data need to be sent to backend (reason doesn't matter).

If the above requirements is what you need, then the scheme is as follows:

1. Implement bound service
2. Service has `addListener(SomeListener listener)` and `removeListener(SomeListener listener)` methods
3. `MainActivity` implements `SomeListener`
4. `MainActivity` (or any other `Activity` or `Fragment` or `Service`) binds the service in `onStart()` and registers itself as a listener when the service is connected (`onServiceConnected()` called)
5. `MainActivity` unregisters from listening to the service in `onStop()` and unbinds
6. Whenever new data available, `Service` checks whether there are any listeners registered and either notifies all the listeners, or sends data to backend if there are none

You can play with this scheme in order to tailor it to your exact needs.